# How to centre pseudo element

Tags: css

I'm trying to create with css a green colored box with a white minus sign in it. I'm trying to get the minus sign to be vertically and horizontally centered within the green box.

I could easily do this by explicity specifying the top and left positions of the pseudo minus sign. However I'm wanting to know if there is another non-explicit way to do this. I was trying `text-align` and `vertical-align`. It's not working. Can anyone out there help?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  height:4em;
  width:4em;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}

.container:before {
  content:"";
  background-color:white;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width:2em;
  position:absolute;
  vertical-align:middle;
  
}
```

```html
<span class="container">

</span>
```

Comment: you mean like in this https://jsfiddle.net/jxLnbLqs/???

Comment: without specifying left or top.

Comment: @Jeeves check my edited answer without using left and top value using flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  height:4em;
  width:4em;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}

.container:before {
  content:"";
  background-color:white;
  height: 0.5em;
  width:2em;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="container">

</span>
```

If you're just doing this for modern browsers, you could add this to your `.container::before {}` styles:

```
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 2):

Give left and top value. Because there is `position: absolute;` for `.container::before`.

And there is no need of `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:middle;` then.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  height:4em;
  width:4em;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}


.container::before {
    background-color: white;
    content: "";
    height: 0.5em;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">

</span>
```

**Edit:**

Another way you can do using `display:flex` without using left and top value. Which support in all latest browser.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
}


.container::before {
    background-color: white;
    content: "";
    height: 0.5em;
    width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">

</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track, just 2 slight tweaks were needed.  Since you used 'em's, this code should also scale nicely.

```
.container:before {
    content:"";
    background-color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 0.5em;
    width:2em;
    position:absolute;
    top: 1.75em;
    left: 0.5em
}
```

What I did is push it 1.75em's from the top.  Since your block is 4em tall, and the minus is 0.5em's tall, exact middle would be 4em/2 - 0.5em/2 = 2 - 0.25 = 1.75.  The same math applies for the left setting: 4em/2 - 2em/2 = 2 - 1 = 1em.